# Login in Flutter with odoo

Tags: flutter, odoo, dio

I'm designing an app that needs to connect to my odoo erp system.
I'm thinking of implementing login.
What do you recommend?

I had started seeing DIO.
The user will have to pass username and password.
in the credentials i also have a DB name and i should figure out how to hide the password inside the code for security reasons.
Then there is the problem of intercepting the cookie to keep the session open.

Comment: why you dont use an odoo api ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Odoo oficial documentation an the External API [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/external_api.html#logging-in).